# finding limits of integrals $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty , (b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

How do I find the limits of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$

where:

$a_n= \int_{-\pi n}^{\pi n} \sin(x)\,dx$ and $b_n= \int_{-2\pi n}^{\pi + 2\pi n} \sin(x)\,dx$ ,  $n\in \mathbb{N} $

I have tried using cauchy, but have no progress.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try computing $a_n$ and $b_n$ explicitly.

Comment: Not sure what the lower bound of $b_n$ is.

Comment: @martycohen yes you are; it is just written oddly.

Comment: Since you have changed it, it is clear, When I commented, it was not. Also, saying "Yes your are" is arrogant.

Comment: marty, I know that you know what $2 n\pi$ is, which is what it originally said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: what happens if you evaluate the integrals for arbitrary integer n? Turn the sequences defined by integrals into sequences of real numbers you can then attempt to analyse.

Also, what do you mean by "using Cauchy?" He did rather a lot of mathematics in his time!

Comment: I got 1 and 2 for $a_n$ and $b_n$ for any n. Since limits of constants are just itself, are the limits 1 and 2 respectively?

Comment: I agree with your results and your statement about the limits, so that is your answer to the question as posed. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Since both
$\sin(x)$
and
$\sin(x+\pi)$
are a
odd,
all the integrals
are zero.

Comment: I do not think $b_n$ is zero...

Comment: @martycohen $b_n$ is 2